# Ensuring data sent via Node socket.write() is fully sent via OS before new data is asked to be sent

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have an application that is acting as a TCP client and will keep trying to connect with a TCP server. Upon establishment of a connection, predefined text messages are sent. The application seems to be working fine at the moment. However, the server expects to receive "one" "complete" message at a time. Everything is on local network on a single switch. All the messages are 500 bytes max roughly. So they will normally get to the server in one go. The issue that i am facing is that I keep sending messages from my NODE app one after the other to the kernel buffer using socket.write() and they seem to be arriving at the destination server together as one long string. Although I didn't send them in one go. Which I believe is OK because its upto TCP to send data as it pleases. But can I ensure somehow that i send a message only when previous message has actually been sent by TCP fully?

Following is the code that is handling socket events.

Thanks.

```
//Socket events-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const socketControl = (constants, vars, status) => {
  //Handle any errors.
  vars.client.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log(`Connection Error : ${error}`);
    //If this happens, close event will automatically be called.
  });

  //Close connection
  vars.client.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Connection closed by server.");
    console.log(
      `Attempting reconneciton with ${constants.REMOTE_SYSTEMNAME} at IP ${
        constants.SERVER_IP
      } at port ${constants.SERVER_PORT} after ${
        constants.RECONNECTTmrPV / 1000
      }s`
    );
    console.log("--");
    status.Connected = false;
    status.socketAvailavleToWrite = false;
    status.waitingcallback = false;
    status.STENReceived = false;

    //Clear watchdog
    clearInterval(vars.heartbeatTmr);
    vars.watchDogCountCurrent = 0;

    //Clear init timer.
    clearInterval(vars.initiateTmr);

    //Attempt conneciton after a certain time.
    //This is a once of call, because this function will get called again if the connection fails.
    setTimeout(
      () => FL_Utils.connect(constants, vars, status),
      constants.RECONNECTTmrPV
    );
  });

  //Handle incoming data.
  vars.client.on("data", function (data) {
    //Add the data to inbound buffer.
    vars.bufferIn = vars.bufferIn + data.toString();
    FL_Utils.processData(constants, vars, status);
    //Handle different types of requests from server here.
  });

  //Drain event, socket available again.
  vars.client.on("drain", () => {
    console.log(`Socket available to write now`);
    status.socketAvailavleToWrite = true;
    status.waitingcallback = false;

    //Check if there are more messages to send.
    //Keep calling this function till there is stuff to be sent in the messageOut buffer.
    if (vars.messagesOut.length > 0) {
      FL_Utils.sendMessage(constants, vars, status);
    }
  });

  //Conneciton established.
  vars.client.on("connect", () => {
    FL_Utils.onConnect(constants, vars, status);
  });
};

module.exports = { socketControl };
```

Following is from another module that sends messages.

```
const sendMessage = (constants, vars, status) => {
  if (vars.messagesOut.length > 0) {
    //Only then try to do anything.

    //Check if the socket is available to write.
    if (status.socketAvailavleToWrite && !status.waitingcallback) {
      let result = false;
      //console.log(`Buffer size at send: ${(vars.messagesOut.length)}`)

      result = vars.client.write(vars.messagesOut[0], () =>
        MessageSendResponse(constants, vars, status)
      );
      //console.log('Callback requested.')
      status.waitingcallback = true;
      if (!result) {
        //The socket is full. Wait for drain event to kick in.
        console.log("Socket is not available to write at the moment.");
        status.socketAvailavleToWrite = false;
      }
    }
  }
};

const MessageSendResponse = (constants, vars, status) => {
  status.waitingcallback = false;

  //console.log(`Buffer size at cb before message shift : ${(vars.messagesOut.length)}`)
  //Message sent.
  console.log(`${timestamp()} : Message out : ${vars.messagesOut[0]}`);

  //Delete message.
  vars.messagesOut.shift();

  //console.log(`Buffer size at cb after message shift : ${(vars.messagesOut.length)}`)

  //Enable the socket available.
  status.socketAvailavleToWrite = true;

  //Check if there are more messages to send.
  //Keep calling this function till there is stuff to be sent in the messageOut buffer.
  if (vars.messagesOut.length > 0) {
    //console.log('Recursive call to send message.')
    sendMessage(constants, vars, status);
  }
};
```

Comment: That's how TCP works. It is a byte-stream protocol. not a messaging protocol.

Comment: I know that. But can i query how many bytes have been sent by the kernel or something like that?